# Case sensitive varchar match with LINQ

Tags: sql-server, linq, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities

What LINQ query can I write to perform a case sensitive match on two varchar columns when I do not have the option of changing or adding to the database schema?

I've considered using COLLATE, but understand that this is not possible with LINQ. Is this correct?

Alternatively, I could use the CONVERT function to match VARBINARY values, but don't know how that can be implemented with LINQ.

Before marking this as a duplicate, consider that I'm looking for a LINQ query and not any solution that involves changing or adding to the database schema.

Comment: Would a solution that performs case-insensitive search in the DB followed by a case-sensitive refinement in memory work in your situation?

Comment: No, unfortunately not. Some smart ass before me put sensitive data in there so it's better left not going over any wire. In fact, I'm doing exactly that right now, but looking for and alternative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try:

```
table.Where(_ => _.col1 == "seArch").AsEnumerable().Where(_ => _.col1 == "seArch");
```

First Where will use SQL server's COLLATE which will return case insensitive results, 2nd where will use case sensitive search.